# Sql Server Connection String Changes When Local and Remote

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, connection-string

Hopefully this will be an easy one.

I have several projects that use a Sql Server 2012 instance on one of our cloud servers. When I am developing on that server my connection string must be .\SERVER_NAME but when I am connecting to it remotely the connection string must be IP_ADDRESS, PORT_NUMBER.  I sometimes forget to change the connection string from local to remote when I push to the production environment.

Is there a way to make both the local and remote connection string the same? Also is there a way to avoid having the port number in the remote address?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the port, the default SQL SERVER port is 1433, if that is the port you are sending then it isn't necessary.  As for having one connectionstring or not changing  the name you could do a couple of things I guess...

Here are some options:

- Add a post deployment task where the correctly configured .config file is copied to the target.
- Code machine specific connections, so both conn strings would be in the web/app .config and based on the runtime machine dictates what conn string you use.
- Add an entry in your host file for the server, on dev it points to DEV Server while on the other sever it points to the other.

Not sure why you must use an IP address and not a name, you must not have any DNS?

Comment: You are correct I do not have DNS services on the remote server. I am going to look into the hosts file option which is a great idea.